# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException with @EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories annotation and SpringBoot 1.4.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm having an issue with Spring boot 1.4.2.M1 and @EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories.

It seems to be a conflict between two beans, one spring boot, one spring-data-neo4j.

Here is a stack trace excerpt:

```
18:12:15.891 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: getSession,org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0
```

And another...

```
Parameter 0 of method setSession in org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - getSession: defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration$SpringBootNeo4jConfiguration.class]
    - org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0: defined by method 'createSharedSession' in null
```

Anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Below is my Neo4j Configuration

```
package com.domain.core.context;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.event.Event;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.event.EventListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.domain")
@EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.domain.core.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class)
public class TestPersistenceContext {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("TheScene.Co: Initializing Test Neo4jConfig ...");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception { 
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.domain") {

            @Override
            public Session openSession() {
                Session session = super.openSession();
                session.register(new EventListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreSave(Event event) {
                        // do something - like set an id on an object
                        log.debug("***** Saving domain object ********");
                    }
                });

                return session;
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration().setCredentials("neo4j", "password")
                .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver");

        return config;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) version `4.2.0.M1`.  This milestone release was put out to get feedback on several big changes from `4.1.x`.

SDN `4.2.0.RC1` should be out later this week but for now `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` is actually quite stable in the lead up to `Ingalls` release train for Spring Data in Decemeber.

[I have written a guide](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html) for users coming from SDN `4.0`/`4.1` which goes over how to upgrade to the snapshot build.

In this guide [there is a link](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university/tree/4.2.x) to an example project branch which shows how to get this version to work with Spring Boot `1.4.x` with a few minor work arounds.

WIth the upcoming release of Spring Boot `1.5`, we have updated all the autoconfiguration to work straight out of the box with SDN `4.2`. We will update the documenation for Spring Boot closer to release.